# MongoDB NoSQL Schema Design

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm with a database design question which i really need some help and advice.

It's for a Auction platform we've built. The initial strategy was "users can bid a single auction", and MongoDB was chosen for the job and so far so good.

Now i'm trying to implement a different schema to support group of auctions, so that a user can create a group of several auctions and costumers can bid a auction or a group.

Group 1

- Auction A
- Auction B
- Auction C

Group 3

- Auction D

I'm struggling with the right approach. Ideally when searching for auctions, the API return would group all auctions within Groups. At least this is the main requirement to implement the group strategy, otherwise it's useless for the costumer.

This is what i thought:

Keep a single collection **Auction**. When a user publish a group store the document per auction and also a extra document for the Group itself (same collection) marked with **groupId** (when null, i know it was the group itself). In this document i would save the properties for the auctions (like sums of minimum budgets, total bids, etc).

But how would i group this and return a group with a list of auctions? Do you think that this's a suitable solution or better, being MongoDB a document db is a good choose for this implementation with groups?

This auction schema it's for services. The current schema is:

**Auctions**

- **Id**
- **CategoriesId, End and Status** - Compound keys
- **Begin**
- **MaxBid**
- **MinBid**
- **Bids** - UserId, Ammount and Date
- **Reputation** - The minimum reputation need to post a bid, based on ammount jobs done, earning and feedback from them

**Category**

- **Name**
- **Description**
- **Stats**

**User**

- **Bids** - Job proposals by the  user: Auction Id, Ammount, Date
- **Auctions** - Auctions created
- **Reputation**
- **TotalEarning**
- **Categories** - Categories Id where the user has done jobs.

Currently the API is filtering auctions by category, end and name. The group implementation would be filtered only by the category.

There're others features in this application but they aren't related to the auction groups.

Comment: What is the current schema? When you say customer can bid an auction or a group, does it mean that the customer can bid a separate auction even if it is in a group? What do you want to query for at a given point?

Comment: I've updated the question. We also use Redis for others needs, so it's an option to do the bids tracking with redis sets instead

Comment: I find your idea of keeping a single collection auction to be a great idea. However marking the group doc with a null groupId may not the best option because you are also having auctions that do not belong to any group. My suggestion is to add a separate Boolean flag field that is true for group and false for simple auction. Now what are the possible queries you plan for the groups?

Comment: Categories. But as the Auction already has compound indexes i would use them also to filter. It's possible to aggregate the documents, in order the Auctions where sub documents of the Groups? I could handle this in clientside but if aggregation or some other feature could handle this in mongo it would be better i guess

Comment: I also reckon your idea to keep a single Auction collection is sound. It seems you've got a simple parent-child relationship going between groups and auctions, and there's a few implementation options for you here: [Model Tree Structures in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures). However in saying this, I still don't quite understand what the purpose of the groups is. Maybe you could elaborate?

Comment: [building an english auction with mongodb - artsy](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2014/04/17/building-an-english-auction-with-mongodb/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to duplicate some of your data for optimal searching. This is perhaps one the things that is most difficult to learn if you're coming from the relational db camp.

Your AuctionGroups collection will need to have enough data about each auction to allow for useful searching -- not just the ID of each auction.

```
AuctionGroups {
 _id : ObjectId,
 name : String, // needed? do the groups have a searchable name/desc?
 auctions: { 
   auctionId : ObjectId,
   auctionDesc : String,
   categoryName : String
 }
}
```

You should add an index (probably full text) for whichever fields you want searchable as part of the auction group. You should include in the AuctionGroup record all of the fields needed to properly display a search result. When a user opens a specific auction, then load the full auction record out of the db. Possibly with slightly updated values. (You'll note if you use ebay regularly that the current bid price and other details on search results is often delayed by a few seconds compared to the actual listing. Same deal.) You can back-push to your AuctionGroups when you update the main Auction entry or on a timer.

Comment: But how would i query auctions with and without groups, i need to query on two collections? Or your proposal is the same collection but with a few more properties? (the solution would be somekind of aggregation).
Yes the groups represents different services that the company is already biding. A group has own documentation on gridfs, permissions, etc.

Comment: There are no mongodb commands to aggregate across more than one collection, so you'll need to put all of the properties you need to query into one collection.

Comment: So you're saying to follow the approach i've suggested on the question, of a single collection and use more properties for the groups? In that case i would use a flag as innoSPG suggested to retrieve only groups and auctions without groups

Answer (score 0):

I am more of a relational DB fella, but nonetheless I would have 2 collections:

1) Group with

- GroupID
- AuctionGroupID :  pointing to the ID of the related "grouped" auction in the Auctions collection
- AuctionIds : list of ids the related "normal" auctions in
  the Auctions collection
- extra search data (will act like a
  cache for all the grouped auctions):

  - [CategoriesID] : aggregated list of categories in the related Auctions
  - minBegin,maxBegin
  - minEnd, maxEnd
  - etc

2) Auctions with additional properties:

- GroupID - which is null for non-grouped auctions
- IsGroup (optional, see below) boolean flag - otherwise you must match the AuctionID with
  the AuctionGroupID in the Group collection to determine if this Auction is the "grouped" one

So the idea would be when a user enters a group:

1. generate a new guid GroupID for the group
2. insert a new
   "record" in the Auctions collection, with a GroupID = the id in step
   1, and optionally IsGroup=true
3. insert a new "record" in the
   Groups collection, with GroupID in step 1) and AuctionGroupID the resulting id from step 2

When the user adds an auction (with AuctionID) to a group (with GroupID):

1. set the GroupID property in the Auction record with that GroupID,
           and optionally isGroup=false
2. add auctionID to the list of auctionIds in the Group record
3. update the agregated information on
   the Group record (categories, minBegin, maxBegin

Notes:

1. You will need to perform step 3) when the user changes any of the
   existing auctions in the group
2. all the auctions in a group plus the grouped auction itself will have the same GroupID in the Auctions Collection

   - if you use the optionall isGroup flag, this will tell you which of those activities is the "group" one
   - otherwise you can tell which one of them is the grouped one by matching it against the AuctionGroupID in the Group record.

This way you can efficiently retrieve all groups and the auctionIds of any group. Then you will have to query the auction Collection with those ids. So yes, you will have N+1 calls to the database (1 for the group plus 1 per auction, but i suppose the number of auctions per group will be small anyway, so it should not be a big deal).

If you want to know if an auction is grouped, then just check if its GroupID is not null, if its get the related Group by its id

That is assuming that one auction can be bound to 0 or 1 group. If you want 1 auction to be boundable to more than 1 group, then just change the GroupID in the Auctions collection into an array